# How to change kernel order in boot menu

Tags: 11.10, 11.04, boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the grub boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

I have 4 kernels in my grub. I want to make my third kernel the first one. How to do it?

Comment: @user16989 The answer for Ubuntu is not necessarily applicable to Debian. There are tools in PPAs that are not there in Debian, for example ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer is a tool to customize grub and may solve the issue on Ubuntu but I doubt it is available for Debian.

Comment: This is a great question. I have edited it to take out the debian bit of it. Even if the answer is not useful to the person posting the question, it will be useful for the community as a whole. BTW @binW, can you add this ppa as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

This from the [Grub Customizer Launchpad.net page](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)
"**Grub Customizer** is a graphical interface to configure the grub2/burg settings with focus on the individual list order - without losing the dynamical behavior of grub."

You can do almost all kinds of customization with it including, but not limited to:

1. Reordering, renaming and disabling entries
2. Changing background
3. Changing timeout
4. Visibility and lot more.

It can be installed with the help of PPA. To install it use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After installation it can be found at Applications -> System Tools -> Grub Customizer