# How can I make Windows boot first and Ubuntu second?

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

How can I make Windows boot first?

Comment: There is a box up there called search, *Use it* this has been answered already.

Comment: @UriHerrera If this has been answered already, then shouldn't you link to the duplicate?

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Links won't show up  correctly on my mobile and i can't seem to be able to click the "Vote to close" button.

Answer (score 1):

(When I searched "make windows boot first" in the askubuntu search box, I had trouble finding a post that answered this question, so I'll answer it here).

I'm going to presume that you are using grub (if you don't know what it is, you are probably using it).

You can change the boot order by editing the menu.lst file located in `/boot/grub/`.

When you look into menu.lst, you want to scroll down to blocks of text that look something like the following:

```
title        ....
root         ....
kernel       ....
...
initrd       ....
```

The block that begins with

```
title        Windows ...
...
```

Is the windows entry that shows up on boot.
If you want this to be both the first and default entry,
you can copy the entire block of text, and paste it just right before the first "title ..." block.

You will have to do this as root (so try `gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst` and make the edits). When you reboot, by default you will boot into windows. Note that because reading Linux filesystems from Windows requires more setup, it is probably best to do this in Linux.

Edit:

Actually after a little more searching, I think the suggestion in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86337/how-to-change-kernel-order-in-boot-menu) is probably a lot safer.

Comment: If he has installed any recent version of Ubuntu, he is likely using Grub 2, which doesn't use the `menu.lst` file (it uses `grub.cfg` instead, which has a different format).  So this answer might not help.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo su
cd /etc/grub.d/
mv 40_custom 08_custom
update-grub
```

this will pull Windows entry in the boot loader on top

Comment: More recently the file is `30_os-prober` so it would be `mv 30_os-prober 08_os-prober` to preserve the name