# How do I change the GRUB boot order?

Tags: boot, grub2

I have both Windows 7 and Ubuntu installed on a shared machine. Because a lot of the non-developers use Windows, I'd like to change the boot order to make it easier for them.

Currently the boot order looks like the following:

- Ubuntu 11.10 kernelgeneric *86
- Ubuntu 11.10 kernelgeneric *86 (safe boot)
- Memory test
- Memory test
- Windows 7 on `/dev/sda6`

How do I change the default order so that Windows 7 is at the top of the list?

- Windows 7 on `/dev/sda6`
- Ubuntu 11.10 kernelgeneric *86
- Ubuntu 11.10 kernelgeneric *86 (safe boot)
- Memory test
- Memory test

Comment: Similar Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990

Comment: Did you do a 'sudo update-grub' after changing the grub file?

Comment: yes I think I may have forgotten to do that, thank you!  I will try and update with the results.

Comment: kubuntu 14.04 `sudo apt-get install kde-config-grub2` then in system config goto startup shutdown

Answer (score 373, accepted):

You can use an easy-to-use the GUI application called [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) to make your life a little bit easier. As the name suggests, you can do much more than just reordering GRUB menu entries with it. You can install it from a PPA in 18.04 and older releases, and from the official repositories in 20.04 and newer.

In 18.04 and older releases, add this PPA (you can skip this command on 20.04 and newer):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

And then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

(See also this Ask Ubuntu [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629))

There is an [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/about/) article about it, *[How to Configure the Linux GRUB 2 Boot Menu the Easy Way](https://www.howtogeek.com/43471/how-to-configure-the-linux-grub2-boot-menu-the-easy-way/)*. Take a look at it if you're interested. Also, there is a solved thread on the Ubuntu Forums, *[Change boot order in GRUB 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1316663)* that mentions this tool.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: GRUB Customizer]

[image: GRUB Customizer - Settings - General]

[image: GRUB Customizer - Settings - Advanced]

---

Some troubleshooting:

The Grub Customizer settings may work only from within the latest Linux/Ubuntu installation, the one that installed the Grub.

For example, if somebody has two OS-es installed (Windows and Ubuntu), and then installs a third OS (Manjaro, etc) and then tries to follow the above answer, Grub Customizer changes will not work when made from the second OS (Ubuntu, in the example). The program has to be installed in the third OS, as it seems that Grub Customizer can only edit the Grub files created by the installation of the system on which itself is installed.

The files that determine the Grub boot menu come in most cases with the latest system installed on a machine, so Grub Customizer has to be installed and used from **that** Linux system.

Comment: Thank you so much! Great answer! I appreciate the screenshots as well!

Comment: Most welcome :) The screenshots come from the blogpost that's linked above :P

Comment: This doesn't work with the latest Ubuntu. Can we get an updated post here?

Comment: @AT How exactly does it not work? What error messages are getting? The PPA is there for the precise series...

Comment: I was running 12.10.

Comment: I think your answer is good and helpful, so please don't get me wrong.  While GUI tools are neat and easy, they hide the facts.  Marve's answer below discusses files in use and how to update them manually, providing insight as to how Grub works.  When the GUI Fails, and it will for some, at least take a peek at the underpinnings - they are not that difficult after all and manual manipulation will probably be easier in the long run.

Comment: I also ran into problems using this tool. It seem like it updates the /etc/default/grub correclty but then it says core dump and aborted.

Comment: If you were like me and couldn't find /etc/default/grub (or it wouldn't update saved changes), try modifying the GRUB_DEFAULT value in /etc/grub.d/00_header (if you have it) and then updating.  It worked for me.

Comment: These screenshots seem irrelevant instructions to most recent grub customizer or Ubuntu versions.

Comment: This needs an update related to the dual levels of current grub menu.

Comment: I installed this and my Win10 installation did not appear as an option in Grub-Customizer.  Then, after restarting my PC, Windows 10 is no longer an option in the bootloader.  So.... now I can't get in to windows at all.  Thanks for the tip.......

Comment: The other **really** important aspect in my eyes: installing this tool is easy. But **un-installation** requires manual work; and as it is about tampering with core elements of your configuration ... not exactly easy. I think you add that information to your answer.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 has the package: 'grub-customizer' in its repository, so no need to add a PPA!

Comment: Ubuntu 20 has it in the "Ubuntu Software" even!

Comment: Now this package `grub-customizer` exists in Debian repository.

Comment: DO NOT USE GRUB CUSTOMIZER. It is apparently riddled with bugs and issues, is impossible to uninstall and/or revert, and totally screwed my system up. Please DO NOT RECOMMEND GRUB CUSTOMIZER.

Comment: @barrypicker When referencing another answer, please provide a link to it rather than mentioning the persons username. The username can change over time (and in this case, it appears that's happened). So there's now now way to know which answer you are referring to.

Answer (score 372):

You can also change the grub default boot entry from the command line without having to install any additional tool.  This won't change the order in the list but it will allow a different OS to boot by default, which sounds like what you may want anyway.

First, make a backup copy of `/etc/default/grub`. In case something goes wrong, you can easily revert to the known-good copy:

```
sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
```

Then edit the file using `vim` or the text editor of your choice:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that contains

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

and set it to

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=x
```

where `x` is the index of grub menu item to which you would like to boot to by default. Note that the menu items are zero-indexed. That means that the first item in the list is `0` and that the sixth item is actually `5`.  So to boot to the sixth item in the list, the line would read:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=5
```

If you forgot the order of the items, take a look at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Each menu entry is specified by a line of type:

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' [options] {
```

You can also chose the default by the name instead of index, e.g.:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT='Ubuntu'
```

if there was a `menuentry 'Ubuntu'` line on `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. This may be a better method, as it does not depend on the order of the entries, which could change.

To use a kernel in the "Previous Linux Versions" sub-menu use:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>x"
```

(make sure to include the quotations), where `x` is the index of the old kernel on the sub-menu, or the name of the kernel as it appears in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. For example,

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-45-generic"
```

Then build the updated grub menu:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Last I looked grub2 generates so many entries on the fly that it's really hard to figure out what number to use for an entry.

Comment: Using an index can be pretty messy - the list of OSes can change after an update. But you can have a look into /boot/grub/grub.cfg and search for the *name* of desired default OS. Then use the quoted name instead of an index. Example: `GRUB_DEFAULT="Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda1)"` instead of `GRUB_DEFAULT=7`

Comment: This needs an update related to the dual levels of current grub menu.

Comment: With the current version of Ubuntu 16.04, if you want to select a specific Kernel to boot to, you need to add to the `Advanced options for Ubuntu` sub menu, like this:
`GRUB_DEFAULT='Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-34-generic'`

Comment: I set `GRUB_DEFAULT=6` and update grub but not work.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal That will attempt to boot the 7th item on your list - is that what you want? If you want the 6th item on your list, use `GRUB_DEFAULT=5`.

Comment: Why doesn't it  work for dual boot with Ubuntu (16.04) and Ubuntu (17.04)? I try to login to 16.04 and try to modify. It didn't do anything at all. The boot order got change after installing Ubuntu 17.04 on a separate partition.

Comment: @Nick, I know that the list is 0 based indexed. But this don't work in my pc.

Comment: Run
`grep -e ^menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
to quickly see your grub menu items. This makes it easier to count (starting at 0) up to the menuentry you want to be the default.

Comment: Show numbered `menuentry` lines, starting at `0`: `grep 'menuentry ' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | nl -v0`

Comment: As  Geoff Williams said, pay attention to submenu: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Submenus

Comment: @KhurshidAlam usually, the last installed OS takes control of the boot loader. Thus you need to configure it in the other Ubuntu.

Comment: GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-26-generic" . This worked like a charm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS x86_64 server edition !

Answer (score 46):

From the [tombuntu site](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/09/25/how-to-change-boot-order-in-ubuntu-11-04/) (article by [Tom](http://tombuntu.com/index.php/author/admin/)):

> GRUB can be configured using the `/etc/default/grub` file. Before you
>   make any changes to it, it may be a good idea to back it up by
>   creating a copy:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.bak
> ```
>
> You can restore the copying the backup over the original:
>
> ```
> sudo cp /etc/default/grub.bak /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> Open the file using the text editor with root privileges:
>
> ```
> gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
> ```
>
> The line `GRUB_DEFAULT=0` means that GRUB will select the first menu
>   item to boot. Change this to `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved`. This change will
>   make it easier to change the default item later.
>
> Save and close the file. Run this command to apply your changes to
>   GRUB’s configuration:
>
> ```
> sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> The configuration change we made allows the grub-set-default and
>   grub-reboot commands to be used at any time. These allow you to change
>   the default boot item permanently or only for the next boot,
>   respectively.
>
> Run `grub-set-default` or `grub-reboot` (with `sudo`) with the number
>   of the menu item to boot (the first item is 0). This command will
>   change the default to the second item:
>
> ```
> sudo grub-set-default 1
> ```

Comment: This answer is taken almost verbatim from http://tombuntu.com/index.php/2011/09/25/how-to-change-boot-order-in-ubuntu-11-04/. Please give credit where credit is due.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to change the order of the boot items.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint Debian Edition.  I didn't have a /etc/default/grub , but found the GRUB_DEFAULT value to modify was instead in /etc/grub.d/00_header .  After modifying GRUB_DEFAULT in 00_header with my desired boot entry name, I simply ran "sudo update-grub" and voila, success.

Comment: I saw these same commands in http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/20/grub2-boot-order-ubuntu-16-04/ I realized that these commands will only work if they were issued from the system in boot order 0 first.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is a very old question and I don't have enough reputation to comment this, so for anyone still looking to do it without Grub-Customizer because of it's infamy:

This method assumes you have a dual-boot with one Linux and a Windows installation. Since the order in `/etc/grub.d` specifies the order in which they are called, you could simply call `os-prober` first and then add the remaining entries.

```
cd /etc/grub.d
mv 30_os-prober 05_os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

This works great and puts Windows on top of the list.

I can't find the source, but will provide it if I come across it again.

Comment: This is by far the simplest solution and works as long as you only  have one OS that is found by os-prober.  In fact, on Ubuntu 20.04, the README inside /etc/grub.d effectively tells you to do exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE STARTING**

*Please note that this will make a large mess of all of your GRUB files. Please be aware of that annoying issue!*
That is all you need to know prior to starting.

On startup, enter Ubuntu. When Ubuntu starts up, enter either the terminal. Enter the following commands:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

When that command opens, chnage GRUB_DEFAULT=0 to GRUB_DEFAULT=saved and then enter. Update GRUB with the command

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally, set default OS with `sudo grub-set-default NUMBER`. NUMBER is the number of the OS that you want to set to default.

---

OR

Install GRUB-customizer with the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Cited from: https://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/20/grub2-boot-order-ubuntu-16-04/

This may provide more detailed information on what you are looking for. I hope this helps.

Comment: This should really accompany a warning that this will make a mess of your grub files and make it difficult to manage without the tool (I'm speaking from experience, as this is my current situation)

Comment: Good point. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

first

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
```

second

```
sudo apt-get update
```

third

```
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Open `Grub Customizer`
And you can edit your grub
You can even change your grub wallpaper
it's a great tool

### Risk Involved whether you use the tool or edit the grub.cfg file

Answer (score -2):

I tried the following and got good results.

Open up a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>),

Type `sudo gksu nautilus` and press Enter.
Type in your user password.

Navigate to the file **`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`**.  Copy and Paste the file into same directory, should create copy of the grub.cfg file for backup purposes.  Then double-click grub.cfg to open the file in a text editor.

In the file you will find the line (`set default="0"`).  Edit the 0 to the line number in Grub that you want to load.  Mine was the sixth line, so I used 5, as the first line is considered 0.  Save the file.  Reboot the pc and if you chose the correct line it will be the highlighted one when Grub loads.

Good luck

Comment: as you can see in the beginning of the file, it says that you should not do this. instead edit `/etc/default/grub` and then run `update-grub`.

Comment: and I wouldn't recommend to gksu nautilus either. Too easy to drop a bomb in your system from there.

Comment: check this post: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/bootmenu

Comment: For some reason this answer is shown as "automatic answer" in google when searching for: "grub change boot order".

Comment: @lepe, don't worry, for me default is http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-change-boot-order-set-default-boot-os-in-ubuntu-14-10-15-04-linux-mint-or-other-derivatives

Answer (score -3):

Open up a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

Type `gksu nautilus` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

That will open up the file browser Nautilus with permission to change files owned by root.

Navigate to the file `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and double-click to open the file in a text editor.

Cut, move and paste the sections in that file that belongs to different operating systems. You must be **very careful** when doing this, as if you do it wrong then you won't be able to boot anymore. Windows boot can always be repaired with the tools from a windows installation disc (`FIXMBR`), that overwrites GRUB-MBR with a typical Windows-MBR.

I have tested it from Ubuntu 9.04 to 12.04 and it has worked fine every time.

But I have only tried to move the Windows boot section to the top of the list to make it become the default.

If my memory is correct, each boot menu section in the file starts with a `begin` ... and ends with an ...`end`. And spans multiple text rows.

The text in that file has become a bit more complicated and it doesn't look the same in the last Ubuntu version as in previous versions. So **use your brain** to save you from doing a mistake.

Comment: Don't you have to run `sudo update-grub` at some point?

Comment: ``/boot/grub/grub.cfg`` is being overwritten at every package installed/updated triggering an update of Grub, effectively invoking ``update-grub``. And that generates a new ``grub.cfg``. Therefore, configuring Grub is done in files in the ``/etc`` directory as explained by the other answers, to make sure it's persistent.

Comment: What I don't understand is what does Nautilus even do for this? How does it have anything to do with boot order changes?