# How can I change the boot order (grub2)?

Tags: boot, grub2, boot-order

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change the grub boot order for ubuntu 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/change-the-grub-boot-order-for-ubuntu-11-10)

I saw guides of setting first operation system to boot. How can I set also the **second** operation system to boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/100246/46531).