# Changes in grub.cfg are ignored

Tags: grub2

I'm trying to change the default OS in grub, but when I do

sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg and change it to option 3 instead of 0 and run update-grub, nothing changes. The default selected OS is still the first one and when I look in grub.cfg it's back to 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated on the top of `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

Edit `/etc/default/grub` instead.

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/110738/43660) are details on how to configure the grub file; see the other answers there for a GUI-based method.

Answer (score 2):

For a small change, just save grub.cfg without update-grub afterwards.

Just realize that anything you do will revert to the information in the scripts the next time update-grub is called.

Thus the reason we don't edit grub.cfg directly.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot about a GRUB installation from source into the `/usr/local` prefix which was reading `/usr/local/etc/default/grub`. I removed `/usr/local/sbin/grub-mkconfig` and reinstalled the system packages  and it works as expected, now.