# How to set default boot kernel in Ubuntu / Grub?

Tags: 11.10, boot, grub2, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the grub boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

I wish to set my installation of ubuntu server 11.10 to automatically boot into linux kernel 2.6.

The way I navigate to this option in the grub menu is by choosing the 3rd option, which says "Older Linux Versions".  This then loads another menu which has the linux 2.6 kernel versions of ubuntu that I am looking for.

How to set up grub so that it boots into the linux 2.6 kernel automatically every time?

Since the option for "Other Linux Versions" is on line 3 of the Grub menu, I changed the line in the `/etc/default/grub` file from `default 0` to `default 2`, but this did not seem to work.

Thanks!