# How do I change default boot kernel if I set it wrong to memtest?

Tags: boot, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the grub boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

O.K., I follow [How to set default boot kernel in Ubuntu / Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156700/how-to-set-default-boot-kernel-in-ubuntu-grub) and make a mistake. I didn't count the entry from 0... I want to set default boot kernel as Linux 3.2.17-chipsee,
count it (begin from 1) from the top, and I get 3. It seems grub will skip those menuentry with recovery mode, and select memtest as default boot option. Now when I boot the machine, it cannot skip memtest. After memtest is done, the machine still reboot into memtest. How can I fix this mistake? I try to boot Ubuntu from the cd-rom, and edit `/etc/default/grub` file on the disk. But it told me that's read-only... Thanks.

```
$ grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.17experimental' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.17experimental (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.17-chipsee' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.17-chipsee (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
```

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.  Changing kernels is different from changing boot priority.

Answer (score 4):

From the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

You can change which kernel grub boots to during the computers start-up.

As the computer starts up.

> Hold down SHIFT to display the menu during boot. In certain cases, pressing the ESC key may also display the menu.

[image]

You should now see the the grub menu. Use the arrow keys to navigate to the correct kernal to boot. Then follow instructions in the above post.

Then follow the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/196661/10998) to fix the menu entry.

Or try the ubuntu community documentation here. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2

Comment: Actually, I did try hold SHIFT, but it doesn't work. Maybe I should press ESC instead. Anyway, I re-install the system... Thanks.

Comment: one of the first changes I make to my installations is to add a longer time out and to show the menu by default. I am a bit of an experimenter, and like to be able to make changes easily. @chenwj

Answer (score 1):

There's a tool called grub customizer that can edit and set the default boot option.

https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer

https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer

Execute these commands one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

[image: grub customizer list]

Comment: Please note now I am booting from the cd-rom and trying to edit `/etc/default/grub` on the disk. This is because I cannot skip memtest, and even it's done, the system still boot into memtest. Can I install the software you said?