# How to change kernel at boot

Tags: boot, kernel, 15.04

I installed the latest kernel (4.1) and want to boot into it instead of 3.9. How can i do this on ubuntu 15.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

You can change which kernel grub boots to during the computers start-up.

As the computer starts up.

Hold down SHIFT to display the menu during boot. In certain cases, pressing the ESC key may also display the menu.

[image]

You should now see the the grub menu. Use the arrow keys to navigate to the advanced options and choose the kernal you want to boot.

[image]

Or try the ubuntu community documentation here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#Configuring_GRUB_2

This is from [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196657/how-do-i-change-default-boot-kernel-if-i-set-it-wrong-to-memtest) post by nelaarThen follow the instructions in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196657/how-do-i-change-default-boot-kernel-if-i-set-it-wrong-to-memtest) to fix the menu entry.

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer) by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

and change the position of entries in the Grub menu. From this you can choose to make the latest kernal as the default entry.

Comment: Just a side note: grub-customizer broke my grub install (made it black with no boot options) not saying noone should use it as it is known to work, just a word of caution

Comment: grub-customizer is for a desktop. You can not run this from the command line.