# Keyboard only works after 1 or 2 reboots Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard

For some reason my keyboard doesn't work when I boot into Ubuntu sometimes. About half of the time. When this happens I have to restart 1-2 times before it starts working again. I'm using a Steelseries 6gv2 keyboard and it works with no problems in Windows. The cursor on login does not blink when this is happening. I have logged in with the on-screen keyboard and can confirm that it does not work when logged in either.

Will add command outputs on request. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have it plugged into an external USB port? Or directly to the machine's motherboard's USB port? I've seen intermittent USB issues on those "USB splitter" type devices (usually due to low amperage)

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1

Comment: It is plugged directly into the motherboard.