# Logitech wireless keyboard stops working after random intervals of time

Tags: usb, keyboard, bluetooth, logitech

I have a Logitech keyboard K830 which used to work perfectly
with Linux (Ubuntu 16.4 long term) but started malfunctioning after an
update around September 2017.

I always used the keyboard through the universal receiver which plugs
to the USB port. I also use a Logitech mouse through its universal
receiver, and the mouse does not show any problems.

The keyboard starts working fine when i plug the receiver and turn it
on, but after a variable amount of time it seems to lose connection to
the receiver. A combination of re-plugging the receiver and
re-starting the keyboard makes the keyboard working for a new variable
amount of time. The keyboard was working seamlessly with the receiver
before September 2017.

When i plug the keyboard and i type `lsusb`, i see the keyboard listed
as the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 098: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

After it randomly loses connection, i don't see that line any longer.

Not sure whether this is relevant: if i type `ls` in
`/sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd`, i only see one address
`0000:00:14.0`, regardless of the number of USB unified receivers i
have plugged.

I found a script online which is supposed to reboot all USB drivers by
cycling those addresses and writing them to `unbind` and `bind`, but
doing so seems not to help with this problem.

There are some questions and answers which seem similar to this
problem and are related to USB autosuspend. I don't have `laptop-mode`
installed and the problem happens also when my laptop is connected to
the grid. I tried:

```
sudo sh -c "echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend"
```

As suggested in the main answer
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-ubuntu-16-04)
but it didn't help.

I tried with a simple USB keyboard with a cable, and it works reliably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rearrange to minimize interference**

> Bus 002 Device 098

Implies that you may have a significant number of usb devices attached to your system. Try rearranging them so that the nano receivers are not near any unshielded devices that can cause interference, such as some flash drives.

It is possible that the keyboards nano receiver is the cause. If so you can use the mouses receiver.

**Pair up to 6 devices to one receiver**

1. Install `solaar`

```bash
sudo apt-get install solaar
```

2. unplug keyboard nano receiver and turn off the keyboard.
3. Pair keyboard to the mouses nano receiver.
   run `solaar-cli pair` and when prompted turn on keyboard.

Comment: could the high number of devices have been due to the experiments i did with bind or unbind? either way, your idea of binding both pheripheral to the working receiver has worked wonders! never gave me a problem since the few days i've been trying it out. thanks a lot man, you literally saved my back as i can now use the wireless keyboard and put my laptop on the roost laptop stand for a decent posture. also, now i have one microreceiver less to keep plugged to my laptop (with the risk of damaging when carrying the laptop around) and an extra free USB slot! you rock man 

Comment: Seems to have worked when I moved it away from the Blue tooth antenna will try for a few days and report back if it did not work

Answer (score 0):

My logitech wireless mouse and keyboard suddenly stopped working intermittently recently.  I found removing and reinserting the unifying receiver would fix the problem, until it didn't.  I installed Solaar, as suggested elsewhere, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: duplicate of the accepted answer

Comment: If a solution has already been provided, and that works for you, then upvote and add a comment rather than making a duplicate answer (which is not allowed). Thanks for your input though.