# How to fix USB mouse and keyboard freezing?

Tags: keyboard, mouse

My wired mouse, wireless mouse, a wired keyboard - all over USB - are freezing every once in a while for a few seconds. Nothing shows up in the logs when this happens and the laptops touchpad and keyboard is still working fine while the USB devices are frozen.

How can I fix this?

Dell Latitude E7470, Ubuntu 17.04, kernel 4.9.45-040945 (I can't use later ones).

Answer (score 3):

Try this command, it is a temporary solution:

`sudo sh -c "echo -1 > /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend"`

I found it on [Keyboard stops working Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772056/keyboard-stops-working-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem! On Ubuntu 16.04 and kernel 4.13.0-36-generic. the post is here:
[External usb mouse and keyboard stop working all of a sudden](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005617/external-usb-mouse-and-keyboard-stop-working-all-of-a-sudden)

I haven't found a solution, I tried some things but nothing happened.

Could it be a problem with the Enablement Stacks in Ubuntu 16.04?
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/02/install-remove-enablement-stacks-ubuntu-16-04/

check this :
[Keyboard and mouse unresponsive after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483416/keyboard-and-mouse-unresponsive-after-suspend)

what I do is suspend the system, then turn-it on and the problem disappears. However after a while it appears again, so I am suspending again...this is frustrating

Answer (score 0):

This one solved the problem permanently for me:
[How can I disable USB autosuspend on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140925/how-can-i-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-ubuntu-18-04)