# How to switch to a signed kernel in Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, kernel

I have multiple kernels installed in my pc. In which an unsigned version is active now. I want to switch back to an older signed version of the kernel.

When I run the following command: `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`

This is what its listing:

1. `ic  linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic 4.15.0-29.31 Signed kernel image
   generic`
2. `rc  linux-image-4.15.0-39-generic 4.15.0-39.42 Signed kernel
   image generic`
3. `ii  linux-image-4.15.0-42-generic 4.15.0-42.45 Signed
   kernel image generic`
4. `ii  linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic 4.15.0-43.46
   Signed kernel image generic`
5. `ii  linux-image-generic 4.15.0.43.45
   Generic Linux kernel image`
6. `ii 
   linux-image-unsigned-4.19.5-041905-generic
   4.19.5-041905.201812031110 Linux kernel image for version 4.19.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP`

The 6th kernel is active now. Which is not signed. And due to that facing lots of issues in updating and installing different packages.

I would like to switch to 4th kernel (Linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic 4.15.0-43.46) signed version.

How to do that? Also is it possible to remove all other kernels?

Comment: Are you the one that installed that unsigned kernel (4.19)?

Comment: The has already been answered, watch at https://askubuntu.com/questions/621393/how-to-change-kernel-at-boot - Answer #2

Comment: How to install a signed kernel

Comment: @Aseem New kernels starting with 4.15.0-18.19 are signed when not mentioned other in the package name. [Bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1764794)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold down (right) SHIFT to display the menu during boot. Use the 4th kernel by selecting it in "Advanced options for Ubuntu" submenu in GRUB during startup. Then proceed with [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels#Other_Methods) to remove the extra kernels.