# HP laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 facing booting problem after kernel update

Tags: boot, 18.04, kernel, updates, hp

I'm using an HP laptop running Ubuntu 18.0. Recently I tried to update the kernel by running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, but after that I was unable to boot into my laptop. I'm getting this error: `Failed to start udev Kernel Device Manager`.

A photo of the screen is attached here. I can't upload a log or a screenshot as I can't access the laptop anymore.

I did some googling, but I couldn't find anything that helped. Also I have some important data that I don't want to lose, so I don't want to reinstall. Is there any way to fix this without losing data?

[image]

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel.

Comment: how can I  revert back to previous kernel ?

Comment: The previos kernel is stell there. You can select it using grub menu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/621393/how-to-change-kernel-at-boot#621395

Comment: Boot to an older kernal via the GRUB "Additional Options" menu, or boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact model # of your HP. Do you also have Windows installed? If so, does it still boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rollback the update and use an older Kernel for now
try this:
[How to change kernel at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621393/how-to-change-kernel-at-boot#621395)