# How can I automatically select Ubuntu at boot-up?

Tags: 12.04, grub2

I want my computer automatically boot my Ubuntu system. But it always starts with this list:

```
Linux 3.2.0-57-generic-pae
Linux 3.2.0-57-generic-pae (recovery mode)
Linux Privous
Memory test (memtest86+)
```

I want my computer to automatically boot into Linux 3.2.0-57-generic-pae.

This is my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```bash
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem=4G video=LVDS-1:d"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Does [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156700/how-to-set-default-boot-kernel-in-ubuntu-grub) help?

Comment: Does that link help? Look at the duplicate as well.

Answer (score 3):

Run this:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

and set this line to `saved`, and remove any `#` from it as well:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

also, set this line to `true`:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

If these lines are not in the file, add them in.

**Edit:**
To get rid of GRUB completely, set this to `0`:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

but as it is sometimes useful for GRUB to be shown, to recover the system, or boot to a different kernel, you may want to set this to 1 or 2 seconds:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
```

you could also hide the menu unless a key is pressed during the `2` seconds time period:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=2
```

Then save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

which will update the configuration. Now, it should automatically select as default the entry you selected previously, and disappear after a timed delay, and hide if you wish it.

More on editing `grub` [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Simple-configuration)

Comment: Depening on your approach, I still didn't solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It is still not work out.

Comment: Try `sudo grub-reboot 0` command on terminal.