# Change boot priority in Grub

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I installed Precise on my friend's computer to use it, but it automatically boots into Precise. He has Xp and wants it to boot into Xp automatically.

How can I set Windows Xp to be the primary boot operating system?

Comment: The duplicate above has a much better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the grub.cfg located at /boot/grub. Change the order OS menu entries in the file.

You can even set time out before the OS is chosen automatically.

Go through this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/CustomMenus

Be very careful while editing grub.cfg

Comment: Sorry but editing grub.cfg is absolutely not recommended for regular usage. The next time `update-grub` is run, your edits are removed. One could tinker with the contents of `/etc/grub.d/`, but that's still not the intended way of doing it. Only when you have a non-functional grub.cfg, because you put the drive in another computer, then you can edit grub.cfg, but you'd run update-grub as soon as you can boot the OS to generate a proper grub.cfg.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by editing `/etc/default/grub`:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

You can change the value for `GRUB_DEFAULT=` to

- a certain number, which is not recommended, because the menu entries can change,
- a string like `"Windows XP"` or however the entry for Windows XP is named; or
- save the last used entry with `GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` and adding `GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true`

after you have made the changes, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to leave. Then run `sudo update-grub` to apply the changes.

I recommend the last option, it's the least annoying option in most cases, unless you boot into another OS each time you reboot.

See also the community documentation for [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2) and [Grub2/Setup](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Setup#A.2BAC8-etc.2BAC8-default.2BAC8-grub).

Answer (score 1):

I followed another forum that used a GUI called grub-customizer

[How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

It was simple and easy and didn't involve you accidentally messing up on the command line or in nano.  This way if you install another OS and it changes the boot order again, you can quickly and easily change it to the way you want!