# How to set Ubuntu to boot first instead of windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10, following the steps outlined in http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html.

However, when I boot my computer, it boots to Windows 10 first. I have to go through Change advanced startup options>Use a device and then choose the third "EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk"  option.

When I am in Ubuntu, when I type in the terminal

```
sudo efibootmgr
```

I get the following results-

```
BootCurrent: 0002
BootCurrent: 0002
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 3004,3001,3002,3003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* Ubuntu
Boot0002* ubuntu
Boot0003* Ubuntu
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3001* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3002* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3004* EFI Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

How do I get make is such that I have the option of choosing between Windows and Ubuntu to boot when I start my computer?

Simple answers will be appreciated!

Edit: The issue is not grub boot order. It is instead UEFI boot order. I have not been able to find a satisfactory resolution to this matter.

Comment: You can boot into grub and do it like in here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/166730/change-boot-priority-in-grub) or the follow up links.

Comment: OP's issue is UEFI boot order not grub boot order. Change post above to show `sudo efibootmgr -v`. What brand/model system. Some will not boot ubuntu entry as they have hard coded UEFI to boot by description. Can you set hard drive entry as first in UEFI boot order? You show 3004 as first, is not 3003 the one that works? But some UEFI seem to reset order. And that may be because Windows BCD syncs order on its updates. Some alternatives. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 If real issues, many find rEFInd works.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the order of operating systems in GRUB using GRUB customizer. Install it using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Open it up and you can easily reorder operating systems under "List Configuration".

Answer (score 0):

In windows, First download "Boot Repair Disk" (will be an iso file, but you can have YUMI or Universal-USB-Installer download and install it rather than doing so yourself).
In Windows go to http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/  and download Universal-USB-Installer (if you only want to work with or from 1 Linux OS with that USB drive) or http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/ and download YUMI (if you want to be able to run multiple OS's from your USB Drive).  Then, once their (or it) downloaded, go to the folder you downloaded it to, right click it, click Properties and click the little button which says "Unblock".  Then you can run the application where you will select your USB drive from the top most drop down box (make certain your USB drive is already inserted and that the drive letter you select is the same as the letter listed in "Computer" for your USB drive), then tell it which OS you want to install to the USB drive in the next drop down box, then click the folder icon and select the location where the iso file for that OS is and select it. Then have YUMI (or universal usb installer) run.  Once it's done you can reboot your computer and choose the USB drive from the boot options (if presented, but your computer may automaticly select the USB drive, or you need to change your BIOS settings to use a USB disk to boot from) and run Boot-Repair.

Or, you can install Boot Repair in Ubuntu if you open that OS rather than windows:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair`

There, you can open the program (and from either Ubuntu or the Boot Repair OS from your USB drive as both will look the same and provide the same functions, except the OS version only has a terminal which does not allow you to paste things which Boot Repair program has told you to use in a terminal so the Ubuntu version is easier), click the "advanced options" drop down at the bottom left of the window, ensure "Reinstall GRUB" is selected (with checkbox), then click the "Grub Location" tab and select Ubuntu as the OS to boot by default, "Place GRUB on all disks". Now click "Apply" and it will run through it's repair (which often includes a group of lines which you have to enter in a terminal and run yourself, but if it shows you more than one command then copy only one line at a time and use it in the terminal). Because you told it to "Boot "Ubuntu" by default it will now automaticlly select Ubuntu to boot when you start your computer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I did not try out your recommendation, because my dual boot laptop was running too slowly, and your solution would require me to have USB drive nearby everytime I wanted to start my laptop. I decided to get rid of dual boot altogether, and installing Ubuntu as my only OS. Thanks once again!

Comment: You do not need it for every boot. You set Windows as the default boot OS and then you reboot and remove your USB drive. You'd only need it again if the Ubuntu kernel was updated and Ubuntu change itself to the default (but you can change that in the /etc/grub.d/ folder's documents/files.