# How to make my MSI computer by default use Ubuntu after installation?

Tags: system-installation, msi

I installed Ubuntu, and it prompted a restart after which when my computer turned on it came to the Windows welcome screen. I know if I restart and press <kbd>F12</kbd> repeatedly it I can get back to Ubuntu, but I want my computer to open with it by default.

Note: I was not able to fix it with this article:
[How to make Ubuntu the default OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964893/how-to-make-ubuntu-the-default-os)

Comment: You didn't mention your machine brand, So I can't say accurate can you try this link as guide.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/964893/how-to-make-ubuntu-the-default-os

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Ubuntu the default OS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964893/how-to-make-ubuntu-the-default-os)

Comment: Okay, I will try this. I am on an MSI computer, with Windows 10.

Comment: Oh okay, I don't know about MSI computer somebody will help you.

Comment: @Kandhaswamy + @ ChanganAuto That post unfortunately did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Hey Tobin! You can tag multiple users in a single comment. @ChanganAuto https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2291269

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Ubuntu to boot first instead of windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/801396/how-to-set-ubuntu-to-boot-first-instead-of-windows-10)

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair your `boot menu` using [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). After that, you will get the boot menu on every startup with all the boot options listed in it.

The startup menu will stay for 5-10 seconds and after that, the system will boot to the default boot entry.

If you find that Ubuntu is not your default boot entry then you can customize it using [Grub-customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

Some helpful Links

1 [how to use grub-customizer](https://askubuntu.com/a/532415/1112104)

Comment: Boot repair will not fix this issue. The problem is that MSI's interface does not accept the already-working Ubuntu UEFI option in the first place, so this will only repair something that won't be called up in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to check some prerequisites in your BIOS settings :
you should run on a full [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) mode and your harddrive partitionning should be GPT (not MBR).
Therefore, with a [UEFI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface) platform you should be able to configure the O/S boot sequence order at 2 stages :

1. the low level UEFI stage order (can be set with BIOS boot sequence priority options) : you can choose any bootable EFI partition (among your windows O/S, linux O/S ... or any of your boot managers installed in an EFI partitions, like grub or windows-boot-manager)
2. the grub stage order (set with `/etc/default/grub`) : can be selected thru GRUB_DEFAULT or/and GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT keys, or manually at runtime

NB : the grub stage will be reached only if you select the grub EFI boot partition in your UEFI sequence, otherwise it will be bypassed (I mean that UEFI stage is the first one taken into account)

Here is an  MSI help page with some tips and MSI BIOS screen shots showing boot priority settings : https://www.msi.com/support/technical_details/MB_Boot_Priority