# How to remove dual boot menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I used to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7. I got rid of Windows and also deleted the partition where it was installed.

Now, in the dual boot menu Windows 7 is still available, and listed as first option. How do i completely remove the menu so that Ubuntu boots directly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the terminal application and enter

```
sudo update-grub
```

This probes for other existing OSes and writes a new grub configuration; since you deleted the windows partition, it shouldn't be in the menu anymore on the next boot.

You can also disable the Grub Os Prober if you like. Just add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` to `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub` again.

**To disable the display of the menu:**

Edit `/etc/default/grub` with elevated rights

and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`

Run `sudo update-grub` again.

Comment: This issue is as of today, after upgrading to 12.10. The grub menu is still there, only the W7 entry has been removed.

Comment: Yes. Thank You. did this: GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true and now ubuntu is booting directly.

Answer (score 5):

> You can use an easy to use GUI app called grub-customizer to make your life a little easy. As the name suggests, you can do much more than just reordering Grub menu entries with it.
>
> You can install it by:

```bsh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

More information in the following page:
[How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: Thanks. But what do i remove now. there are multiple values that are unknown to me.

Comment: You should remove only the windows 7.

Comment: Did what you said and W7 entry is now gone. How do I remove the WHOLE list and let ubuntu boot directly and by default?

Comment: If you installed that GUI than there is a `show menu` option. Uncheck that