# How can I remove the items form grub boot list

Tags: grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove dual boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204218/how-to-remove-dual-boot-menu)

This my grub boot loader and it show that I have two OS and I want other lines to remove it specially under line because it make anyone can edit it and make trouble for boot systems

So how can remove it or change?

[image: grub load]

Comment: sorry but the problem that bottom lines not appear to remove so i asked for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Grub Customizer software by Daniel Richter.
Run the following code in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

then open the application(with Unity Dash or with **grub-customizer** command in Terminal).Delete lines whatever you want.

Comment: thanks you man it help me but

the bottom line it said use the and keys to select with entry

this lines can't edit or remove it

Comment: I am researching it now @Mahmoud20070

Comment: ok sir i waill wait

Comment: Sorry, the thing you want, is in the compiled GRUB. The idea: "Modifying grub localization file in order to delete the lines you want" crossed to my mind. But localization is mounted in compiled GRUB so if you still want delete the lines , you must edit en_GB.po(or like this) file and recompile the GRUB.As for me,give up :) Or you can edit the GRUB's software codes and recompile them.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the memtest by removing the "memtest86+" package from your computer, followed by a "update-grub2".

The other lines (at the bottom) can't be removed as far as I know.

Comment: this problem i really need to edit it because its very dangerous and anyone can edit it and make trouble for me