# Windows not appearing in GRUB

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, 16.04, boot-repair

I have a Macbook pro running both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04. When I initially installed Ubuntu, I received an internal error which didn't cause the desktop to load, so I reinstalled it. At the time, I didn't like grub, so I decided to convert the partition into empty space. After installing Ubuntu and rEFInd, when I tried to switch over to Windows, I was brought to the grub rescue terminal where it said that boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod was not found. I already ran boot repair, the log for it is right here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17234595/, but it still didn't fix the problem nor did running sudo update-grub. Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266429/error-file-grub-i386-pc-normal-mod-not-found)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. I created a bootable USB drive with the Windows 10 ISO using UNetbootin. I booted into the Windows 10 installation screen and clicked repair your computer. After that, I clicked Advanced options then command prompt. In command prompt, I typed in the following commands:

```
bootrec.exe /FixMBR
DISKPART
SELECT DISK 0
SELECT PARTITION 4
ACTIVE
```

The disk and partition numbers may be different depending on what disk and partition windows is installed on. To see the disks and partitions on the computer, enter `LIST DISK` OR `LIST PARTITION`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have uninstalled the windows boot loader when you converted the grub partition to blank space. You may have to reinstall windows.