# Windows option doesn't show up in GRUB menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I just got my PC back from the service where they changed the power supply. Probably that changed the setup for the dual boot I have already set up. I have installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu. When I tried to start the PC, in the grub menu there is only Ubuntu and not Windows. Tried to fix it with boot-repair but it didn't work. [Here is the link from boot-repair](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vWpfRvqJBS/)

I have tried `update-grub`, editing the `custom_40` file with:

```
menuentry "Windows 10" --class windows --class os {
   insmod ntfs
   search --no-floppy --set=root --fs-uuid $your_uuid_here$
   ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

with the correct uuid. Windows 10 appeared as an option but when I enter it shows the errors:

```
file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntfs.mod' not found

file '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/ntldr.mod' not found
can't find command 'ntldr'
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @karel yes i already read that. But the guy there had win8 and win10 in his system. Also i have done the obvious update-grub and adding the commands in the replies in the custom_40 file but none of these worked :/

Comment: @karel tried the commands in the answers but again an option is created but i'm missing some files

Comment: You need to boot in legacy-mode, that's all. Enter your UEFI-settings and choose correct boot device, dont choose the `ubuntu`-entry, that's for EFI-mode, instead boot to your HDD, then grub will open, choose ubuntu then and run `sudo update-grub` again. You have an obsolete boot-loader for ubuntu on your drive which will boot in efi-mode, but grub is also in MBR.

Comment: @mook765 oh god it was easier than i expected. Thank you!

Comment: Also move boot flag using gparted back to sda2. Grub does not use boot flag to boot Windows, but grub also only boots working Windows. And you can only run Windows repairs if boot flag is on sda2. Windows eventually will turn fast start up back on, and then you need to directly boot Windows with either your Windows repair disk or temporarily installing a Windows boot loader, fixing Windows & restoring grub to MBR. Windows 10 with its fast start up/hibernation is not particularly dual boot friendly, even with another install of Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list)

Answer (score 2):

As [suggested by @mook765](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162678/windows-option-doesnt-show-up-in-grub-menu#comment1937445_1162678) all I had to do was to change the boot order and make boot option #1 from hard drive and not Ubuntu. With that way Windows loaded with no problem!