# Windows 10 not showing in GRUB boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have read similar questions on various websites but haven't solved my issue. Thanks in advance for your help.

I installed Ubuntu on a Dell server with Windows 10 pre-installed as dual boot.

During booting, Windows 10 is not in the GRUB boot menu.

However, I can still boot into Windows by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> during booting to get into BIOS? then choosing Windows BootMgr.

```
$ sudo ls /boot/efi/EFI
BOOT  ubuntu

$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0008,0009,000A,000C,000D,000E,000F
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1a291e8a-bf72-4171-adb6-6244b30625ee,0x800,0x145000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...e................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(5,GPT,015d35bf-e5ff-4267-8fe3-d0b70583083f,0x7286c800,0x1ad000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0008* Onboard NIC (IPV4)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(e4b97af857c8,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)..BO
Boot0009* Onboard NIC (IPV6)    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1c,0x3)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(e4b97af857c8,0)/IPv6([::]:<->[::]:,0,0)..BO
Boot000A* Diskette Drive    BBS(Floppy,,0x0)..GO..NO[.......+.D.i.s.k.e.t.t.e. .D.r.i.v.e.........................rN.D+..,.\...........BO
Boot000C* Hard Drive    BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NOS.......+.H.a.r.d. .D.r.i.v.e.........................rN.D+..,.\...........BO
Boot000D* USB Storage Device    BBS(PCMCIA,,0x0)..GO..NOc.......+.U.S.B. .S.t.o.r.a.g.e. .D.e.v.i.c.e.........................rN.D+..,.\...........BO
Boot000E* CD/DVD/CD-RW Drive    BBS(USB,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.C.D./.D.V.D./.C.D.-.R.W. .D.r.i.v.e....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.Z.K.J.P.E.3.1.J.2.5. .7. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot000F* NetWork   BBS(Network,,0x0)..GO..NO........g.N.e.t.W.o.r.k.........................rN.D+..,.\...........8..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.K.i.l.l.e.r. .E.2.4.0.0. .B.o.o.t........BO
```

Under Linux, failed to find `bootmgfw.efi` with `sudo find . -name "bootmgfw.efi"`

[Boot info output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z3nqt4Rj9H/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/) and [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Comment: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup

Comment: Is Windows hibernation on? Or if fstab mount of efi partition still is 0077, it is hidden for security reasons. You are showing two different ESP - efi system partitions, one Windows & one Ubuntu? If same drive, you really should only have one ESP. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred . Thanks.  the Windows hibernation is off. the fstab mount of EFI partition is 0077. What confuses me is by pressing F12 during boot, I get into boot mode screen, it shows the current boot mode is : UEFI mode with Security Mode off. Under UEFI option, I see both "windows 10" and "Ubuntu", thus I can boot into Windows 10 from there.  Does it mean the Windows 10 boot loader file -- bootmgfw.efi is somewhere on the disk , just GRUB couldn't locate it ?

Comment: Did you reinstall as that may create a new partition with different UUID? But even then grub updates in Ubuntu still should find it. But you may have an old entry somewhere? That is detail that Boot-Repair report will show. Best not to run Boot-Repair auto fix until someone reviews report. Usually it works, but occasionally it creates issues. Any fixes will change mount of ESP also from 0077 to defaults so it can edit fstab. I use defaults, but it may be better to change back to 0077 later.

Comment: @oldfred, please see the boot info at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z3nqt4Rj9H/.  what is the default file mode for ESP ( currently it is 0077 )

Comment: Before 14.04 Ubuntu used defaults and since has used 0077 to prevent access. I believe that is for security, but I want to update ESP myself sometimes. I am debating changing back to 0077. Boot-Repair auto changes it, also. Script did not show any Windows boot files. UEFI shows a Windows entry from another ESP which does not exist. And your sda1 cannot be seen, is it a corrupt ESP that was for Windows & then Ubuntu added a new one?

Comment: this says fast start up on: line 520 in report: Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)

Answer (score 0):

Update your grub2 using this command:
`sudo update-grub2`