# Can't see Windows 10 in GRUB

Tags: grub2, windows-10

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 and now I can't launch it. I first had some problems when installing Ubuntu, so I reinstalled it. Afterwards, there is no Windows option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list)

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and run the command:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

This will update GRUB and show you a list of all the OSes installed. You should see  options like Ubuntu 18.04, Windows 10, etc.