# How do I add Windows boot option to the grub menu ar boot up or whatever to be able to boot into my Windows 10 partition?

Tags: grub2, windows-10, grub-efi

I'm dual booting Linux and Windows 10. I've had Linux on my Lenovo 130 15ast for a little while. I was just messing around and all the sudden I made a mistake and now I can't get the Windows 10 boot option back in the Grub boot menu. This is what I tried to do from the grub prompt:

```
grub> chainloader +1
error: invalid EFI file path
grub> ls (hd0,gpt1)/
efi/
grub> chainloader (hd0),gpt1)/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi boot
error: file `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found  
grub> _
```

Then I tried (gtp2 ) grub returned `error: unknown filesystem`

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add Windows 10 to GRUB OS list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list)

Comment: What version Ubuntu? What is "*I was just messing around and all the sudden I made a mistake*"?