# How to add Windows 10 to GRUB menu, when missing after Focal install and boot-repair?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have installed Focal (dual boot, Windows 10 was already installed), and the GRUB menu lists only Ubuntu, no Windows, which was customary on my PC also with previous Ubuntu releases. With previous releases, however, running `boot-repair` would fix the issue, but not this time.

Oddly enough, when I see the GRUB menu if I:

- hit [Esc] to enter the GRUB CLI
- type `exit` to leave the GRUB CLI

then the system boots straight into Windows 10.

I have also run `sudo grub-update` but no change.

Under Windows 10, I have run `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` but no change. I noticed that under C:\Windows\Boot\EFI there is no ubuntu directory, and can't find a `shimx64.efi` in there.

In the motherboard UEFI I can choose two other entries to boot from, but one behaves the same, and the other boots straight into Windows 10, with no GRUB menu.

This is a pastebin with the report from `boot-repair` https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6ZHvQqSfMN/

Here below the `/etc/default/grub`

Any other information I can collect to troubleshoot the issue?

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

[Additional info]
I have two SSDs configured as RAID 0 with Intel RST. On that RAID, I have both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. See pic below. In the UEFI BIOS, Sata mode selection is set to RAID, no AHCI.
[image: Intel RAID config]

After removing the boot entry as per oldfred recommendation (with `efibootmgr`), the PC booted directly into Windows 10, without showing the GRUB menu anymore. From there, I modified the boot entries again to  regain access to Ubuntu; I also tried running `boot-repair` one more time,  this is the current status:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 000E
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 000E,0000,0007,0004,0009,0001
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,baeb537c-b470-48ab-ae4c-4663a62e8d2a,0x109000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...,................
Boot0001* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........o.H.L.-.D.T.-.S.T. .D.V.D.R.A.M. .G.H.2.2.N.S.7.0....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.2.K.B.Z.9.8.5.8.2.5. .9. . . . . . . . ......AMBO
Boot0004* ST31000524AS  BBS(HD,,0x0)AMGOAMNO........m.A.0.S.0. .T.O.S.H.I.B.A. .H.D.W.D.1.2.0.........................rN.D+..,.\...........>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.A.0.S.0. .T.O.S.H.I.B.A. .H.D.W.D.1.2.0......AMBOAMNO........g.A.0.S.1. .S.T.3.1.0.0.0.5.2.4.A.S.........................rN.D+..,.\...........8..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.A.0.S.1. .S.T.3.1.0.0.0.5.2.4.A.S......AMBOAMNO........_.I.n.t.e.l. .V.o.l.u.m.e.0.........................rN.D+..,.\...........0..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.I.n.t.e.l. .V.o.l.u.m.e.0......AMBO
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,baeb537c-b470-48ab-ae4c-4663a62e8d2a,0x109000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)
Boot0009* Removable Drive   BBS(Floppy,,0x0)AMGOAMNO..........G.e.n.e.r.i.c. .M.a.s.s.S.t.o.r.a.g.e.C.l.a.s.s.1.5.3.6....................A.....................................N..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.G.e.n.e.r.i.c. .M.a.s.s.S.t.o.r.a.g.e.C.l.a.s.s.1.5.3.6......AMBOAMNO..........G.e.n.e.r.i.c. .M.a.s.s.S.t.o.r.a.g.e.C.l.a.s.s.1.5.3.6....................A.............................N..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.G.e.n.e.r.i.c. .M.a.s.s.S.t.o.r.a.g.e.C.l.a.s.s.1.5.3.6......AMBO
Boot000E* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,baeb537c-b470-48ab-ae4c-4663a62e8d2a,0x109000,0x32000)/File(EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
```

Comment: You have two Windows UEFI boot entries and one is using shim(grub's secure boot). Compare Boot0000 and Boot0007 starting line 69. Best to remove 0000 and only have correct Windows entry. You are using Microsoft dyamic partitions. "Microsoft LDM data` Line 136 Best not to use dynamic, Linux does not work with it. Do not understand how sda & sdb can be RAID as not same partitions? Do you have RAID/Intel RST on, and not AHCI?

Comment: I have update the issue with info.

Comment: Your `sudo efibootmgr -v` still looks like the original list as 0000 is Windows description but booting Ubuntu. What brand/model system? What version of Ubuntu, 20.04.1? And Server used to be the only one that installed with RAID, well.  But RAID is identical partitions on two or more drives. You do not have identical partitions. The Intel RST is just another driver that lets you use one or more drives, that may or may not actually be RAID. Linux used to not work with RST and you had to change to AHCI driver.

Comment: It is a custom build with an old P8P67 EVO motherboard and Intel i7-2700K CPU. I recall that before Ubuntu 18.04 I had to install server and then the desktop on top of it, but since 18.04 (if I am correct) also the desktop install recognizes RAID.

->  lsb_release -a 
LSB Version: core-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu2-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to make `boot-repair` work in my case, even after a fresh install of Win 10 and Focal, but have been able to manually add an entry for Win to the GRUB menu following the instructions here: https://askubuntu.com/a/977251/528780