22.04 to 24.04.1 upgrade overwrote my windows partition
I was using Ubuntu 22.04 along with Windows 10 dual boot style. However today I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04.1 from whatever menu link it provided. 24.04.1 came up well ... however I can no more access Windows. When I power on the system it no more gives me a choice to choose between Windows or Ubuntu... like it used to do.
Any guidance on how to recover from this situation?
Thanks in advance.

I tried the above suggested way:
$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for xxxxxx: 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found memtest86+x64 image: /boot/memtest86+x64.bin
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done

However after reboot it directly boots ubuntu ... without giving me the choice of os s. I rebooted twice as one of the suggestions expressed.
Please see if there is anything that I might have missed/overlooked.
Thanks to all of you for your time.

Run sudo update-grub in a terminal, hopefully it will fix it otherwise there is this https://askubuntu.com/questions/661947/add-windows-10-to-grub-os-list

use boot-repair advanced options, and select purge grub before reinstall it. Ubuntu 22.04 is based on grub 2.06 while Ubuntu 24.04 is based on grub 2.12. this make a conflict after upgrading the system

Just to check - have you got backups of your Windows data? If not, I would pause now, don’t try anything else other than booting into a live USB Ubuntu session and use that to identify your Windows partition (assuming it’s still there, which it probably is) - and back up anything important. Then you can try resolving it - if you fail, the worst case scenario is you have to reinstall - but at least you haven’t lost any data.

Do you have Secure Boot enabled in your firmware settings? If so, turn it off.
You may also need to install and enable the os-prober tool which detects other OSes:
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/11/dual-boot-os-disappear-after-ubuntu-22-10/
