# How to change boot priority?

Tags: boot, laptop, live-usb, bios

I have a laptop with Ubuntu installed as the only OS. I also have a USB stick with a Windows 7 installation on it. I want to install Windows from the USB stick on my laptop but when I try to restart the laptop to get access to BIOS, I can't seem to find the command for it, its like it skips everything and just says Ubuntu and then takes me to the login screen.

How do I change the boot priority to USB in Ubuntu?

Comment: On some systems you have to press `F2` or `Esc` to access Bios settings. On others it is `CTRL + Alt + ESC`.

Comment: @ToDo you can write it as answer .

Comment: @OP in some systems it will access with DEL key .

Answer (score 7):

On some systems you have to press <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to access Bios settings. Less frequently it is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Once in Bios settings, on some systems, while there is a boot order giving you "removable drives" and "primary hard disk" as options, you may have to set the boot order again in an item labelled "HDD's" where you find again the USB drive.

Answer (score 7):

The boot priority settings are often found under the Boot tab of the computer's BIOS/UEFI utility. The BIOS/UEFI utility can be accessed by pressing the key which is shown on the manufacturer's splash screen when booting. This is the <kbd>F12</kbd> key on many computers. The keys to press, such as <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, differ on computers from different manufacturers. When grub bootloader is installed it does not change the key which is used to access the BIOS/UEFI utility.

[image]

When the power button is pressed to start the computer, it will try to boot first from whatever option is listed first in the boot priority section of the computer's BIOS/UEFI utility. If a USB flash drive is listed first in the boot priority list, it will try to boot from the USB flash drive first. If the internal hard drive where Ubuntu is installed is listed first in the boot priority list, the computer will boot to Ubuntu.

---

#### Boot menu and BIOS access keys<sup><sup><sub>[source](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779)</sub></sup></sup>

```
Manufacturer    Models                                  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key    
Acer            Aspire One zg5, zg8, Aspire Timeline    F12             F2    
Acer            Aspire v3, v5, v7                       F12*            F2  
Acer                                                    Esc, F2, F12    Del, F2

Manufacturer    Models              Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Apple           Post-2006 models    Option

Manufacturer    Models              Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Asus            Desktops            F8              F9  
Asus    VivoBook f200ca, f202e, q200e, s200e, s400ca, s500ca, u38n, v500ca, v550ca, v551, x200ca, x202e, x550ca, z202e  Esc     Delete  
Asus    N550JV, N750JV, N550LF, Rog g750jh, Rog g750jw, Rog g750jx Zenbook Infinity ux301, Infinity ux301la, Prime ux31a, Prime ux32vd, R509C, Taichi 21, Touch u500vz, Transformer Book TX300  Esc (Disable "Fast Boot" and "Secure Boot Control")     F2  
Asus    k25f, k35e, k34u, k35u, k43u, k46cb, k52f, k53e, k55a, k60ij, k70ab, k72f, k73e, k73s, k84l, k93sm, k93sv, k95vb, k501, k601, R503C, x32a, x35u, x54c, x61g, x64c, x64v, x75a, x83v, x83vb, x90, x93sv, x95gl, x101ch, x102ba, x200ca, x202e, x301a, x401a, x401u, x501a, x502c, x750ja     F8  Delete  
Asus            Eee PC 1015, 1025c  Esc             F2

Manufacturer    Models   Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Compaq          Presario Esc, F9         F10

Manufacturer    Models   Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Dell                     F12**            F2

Manufacturer    Models   Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
eMachines                F12             Tab, Delete  
Gateway  

Manufacturer    Models   Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Fujitsu                  F12             F2

Manufacturer    Models   Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Gigabyte                 F12             Del

Manufacturer    Models                           Boot Menu Key                           BIOS Key  
HP                                               Esc, F9                                 Esc, F10, F1  
HP              Pavilion Media Center a1477c     Esc                                     F10  
HP              Pavilion 23 All In One           Esc (Select boot media from the menu)   F10  
HP              Pavilion Elite e9000, e9120y, e9150t, e9220y, e9280t     Esc, F9     F10  
HP              Pavilion g4, g6 and g7, Probook 4520s, 4525s, 4540s, 4545s, 5220m, 5310m, 5330m, 5660b, 5670b   Esc     F10  
HP              Pavilion HPE PC, h8-1287c, Pavilion PC, p6 2317c, Pavilion PC, p7 1297cb, TouchSmart 520 PC, ENVY x2, m4, m4-1015dx, m4-1115dx, sleekbook m6, m6-1105dx, m6-1205dx, m6-k015dx, m6-k025dx, touchsmart m7, Envy, dv6 and dv7 PC, dv9700, Spectre 14, Spectre 13, 2000 - 2a20nr, 2a53ca, 2b16nr, 2b89wm, 2c29wm, 2d29wm    Esc (Then F9 for "Boot Menu")   Esc  
HP              2000                             Esc (Then F9 for "Boot Menu". Select "Patriot Memory" on the Boot Option Menu)  Esc
HP              Pavilion a410n                   Esc                                     F1

Manufacturer    Models  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Intel                   F10

Manufacturer    Models  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key
Lenovo          IdeaPad s300, u110, u310 Touch, u410, u510, y500, y510, yoga 11, yoga 13, z500  Novo Button (in the left corner of the laptop), F12     Novo Button  
Lenovo          IdeaPad P500                                    F12 or Fn + F11    F2    
Lenovo          IdeaPad S10-3, g460, g470, g475, g480, g485     F12                F2

Manufacturer    Models                  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key    
Microsoft       Surface Pro 1-3                         Volume-Down Button   
Microsoft       Surface Pro 4 & Book                    Volume-Up Button

Manufacturer    Models  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
NEC                     F5              F2

Manufacturer    Models  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Packard Bell            F8              F1, Delete

Manufacturer    Models                  Boot Menu Key                           BIOS Key  
Samsung                                 F12, Esc                                F2, F10    
Samsung         NC10, np300e5c, np300e5e, np350v5c, np355v5c, np365e5c, np550p5c    Esc     F2
Samsung         Series 5 Ultra, Series 7 Chronos, Series 9 Ultrabook    Esc (Must disable "Fast Boot" in BIOS)  F2  
Samsung         Ativ Book 2, 8, 9       F2 (Must disable "Fast Boot" in BIOS)   F10

Manufacturer    Models  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key   
Sharp                                   F2

Manufacturer    Models          Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key   
Sony            VAIO Duo, Pro, Flip, Tap, Fit   Assist Button (Use the Assist Button when the computer is off, not when it is booting)  Assist Button (Use the Assist Button when the computer is off, not when it is booting)  
Sony            VAIO, PCG, VGN  F11             F1, F2, F3  
Sony            VGN             Esc, F10        F2

Manufacturer    Models                      Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
Toshiba         Kira, Kirabook 13, Ultrabook, Qosmio g30, g35, g40, g50, Qosmio x70, x75, x500, x505, x870, x875, x880  F12     F2  
Toshiba         Protege, Satellite, Tecra   F12             F1, Esc  
Toshiba         Equium                      F12             F12

Manufacturer    Models  Boot Menu Key   BIOS Key  
ASUS                    F8              DEL  
Gigabyte                F12             DEL  
MSI                     F11             DEL  
Intel                   F10             F2  
Asrock                  F11             F2, DEL  
EVGA                    F7              DEL
```

<sup>*****</sup>`F12 Boot Menu` must be enabled in BIOS.
<sup>******</sup>Select `USB Flash Drive`.

If you can't get into the BIOS setup utility at all because it's password protected and you forgot the password you can remove the BIOS password by removing the [CMOS battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/old-zt-computer-tower-isnt-booting-from-xubuntu-minimal-cd/528196#528196) for 5 minutes and then putting it back in. This will also reset all BIOS/UEFI settings back to their defaults.

Answer (score 5):

For gaining access to the BIOS to edit boot order, you usually need to press the F2 or F12 key during that brief splash screen right after hitting your power button (it usually only lasts a second or two so you have to think fast) Once in, you should be able to either choose to boot from USB or move it to the top of the Boot order. Google around for the correct key for your specific computer model and you should be able to find out how to get into the BIOS.

As for installing Windows along side your Ubuntu Installation, remember that Windows will write over the Master Boot Record (MBR) and you will not be able to boot into your Ubuntu installation until you re-install the Ubuntu's Grub boot loader.

Directions for how to do this are here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

You might then also wish to know how to change the boot order once you have the two OS's installed and running.  You will have to edit the file /etc/default/grub
directions for doing this are here: [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Hope this helps enough to get you started with your dual-boot system. There are some great guides on how to set up an ideal Windows 7 and Ubuntu dual boot set up if you Google around a bit.

Answer (score 3):

| Device | Key Combination | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Acer | Del or F2 | F2 key most likely |
| Asus | Delet or Del |  |
| Compaq | F10 |  |
| Dell | F2 |  |
| eMachines | Tab or Del |  |
| Fujitsu | F2 |  |
| HP | Esc, F10, F11 | Other possibilities: on Pavilion - F1 |
| Lenovo | F1 or F2 | Other possibilities: small button next to the Power button (if laptop) |
| Samsung | F2 | For ultrabooks from Samsung if might be F10 |
| VAIO | F1, F2, F3 | Other possibilities: Assist button |
| Toshiba | F1, F2, F12 or Esc |  |