# Making a Live USB of Kali

Tags: live-usb

Since 2 days I am trying to make a live bootable USB of Kali Linux, but I have been unsuccessful.

I downloaded the .ISO LIVE image. But it didn't boot. My Dell-Inspiron5593 shows one time boot option when I try to boot from USB. It shows two USB partitions but none of them boots.

Today I downloaded the .ISO image. It downloaded pretty fast, within an hour (3.3G). When the download was completed my system projected as if I had inserted the USB and it showed the two partitions of the USB on my right screen corner.

When I checked for the USB in the terminal, there was no USB drive (Of course I had no USB inserted).
When I checked for the location of the downloaded .ISO file, it was on a temp folder of moz_temp .
When I restarted my system the USB icons on the right corner went away. The amazing thing was that the downloaded file was also missing.

I was intending to make live USB of Kali Linux to learn hacking.
I am thinking I can learn hacking without Kali Linux? Is this possible if I add the necessary packages to my Ubuntu 21.04?

Comment: Like any other ISO distributed installation media you need to use some tool to "burn" it to the USB. Ubuntu has the Startup Disk as default but other can be used like MKUSB, etc.

Comment: Many of the Kali Linux tools are standard Debian tools that are also available in Ubuntu; that however is not all (some small tools are Kali Linux specific).  Also FYI: Kali in Debian and Ubuntu refers to a drawing program (see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=kali&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=kali) so it's Kali Linux and not Kali (unless using a Kali Linux site).

Comment: Thinking you need Kali Linux for "hacking" is maybe the greatest misunderstanding of all time.  Learning "hacking" is actually learning about networking, processes, scripting, system utilities etc., which you might as well do on Ubuntu. Kali Linux is a specialized distribution for pentesting purposes - this isn't the same as "learning hacking".

Comment: I assume that this question primarily targets how you make a bootable Live USB from Ubuntu.  Not to sound harsh, but if you intend to learn "hacking", learning how to create a bootable USB is an excellent start: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu (and yes, this tutorial is equally valid, not matter if it's an Ubuntu or Kali image you put on the stick).

Comment: You can make a Kali Live USB using Universal, YUMI, Win32DiskImager, Ventoy, dd, SDC, mkusb and Gnome-Disks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a bootable Clonezilla USB that works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477573/how-to-create-a-bootable-clonezilla-usb-that-works)