# I'm attempting to resize a locked partition but I keep running into some issues

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb

When I initially installed Ubuntu, I was running both Windows and Ubuntu in separate partitions. However, at one point I decided to run just Ubuntu and basically deleted the Windows partition and consolidated it into one large one. I realize now in hindsight that was rather foolish and now I am attempting to once again resize it.

[image: GParted hard drive pic] (this is how my Partition looks at time of posting)

From everything I've read, I realize I cannot edit the partition because it's the one that I'm currently using and so I have made multiple attempts at using a 16GB USB Drive to make a live boot USB but any attempt to do this has so far failed. I've tried using the builtin system tools as well as using Ventoy.

(which oddly enough allows me to create a live USB and even goes as far as loading into the recovery screen but then fails when I attempt to boot it.)

I realize most people might just remake an Ubuntu Live USB instead and go through the whole "try it" process but I'm running off cell data in a fairly remote location and so downloading the 3GB OS unfortunately isn't an option at this point.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your actual problem is creating a live USB without downloading an .iso, please edit your question to focus on that and remove all the extraneous piffle. Also fix the title.

Comment: Where is your install media? Can you not boot up this?

Comment: Your actual question has almost nothing to do with what you wrote about. This question needs to be entirely rewritten. I am voting to close as "needs focus". Rewrite the question so that it is about your actual problem. Alternatively, ask about the other problem instead of asking how to perform some solution that you think will fix that problem. See: [What is the XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: You can download a **gparted mini-system iso file** from [this link](https://gparted.org/download.php). The size is only 456 Mibibytes. When cloned to USB it boots in BIOS mode (alias legacy mode). When extracted to a FAT32 partition it boots in UEFI mode. See also [this link 'iso2usb'](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb) describing how to make the USB drive bootable (with gparted or some other typical linux system including Ubuntu).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/q/126153/) and [How to create a bootable Clonezilla USB that works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477573/how-to-create-a-bootable-clonezilla-usb-that-works)