# How to set USB flash drive as first boot device in dell inspiron 15

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, dell, bios

i m trying to install ubuntu on Dell Inspiron 15 using USB flash drive using USSB installer. But in booting sequence there are only two boot options. Legacy boot and UEFI boot mode. Can anyone tell me that how can i set the first boot device = USB flash drive.???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reformat the USB and put Ubuntu on it. When booting, you'll have to press a certain key to bring up the BIOS. There should be a menu that allows you to change boot order.

Comment: yeah, i have put ubuntu on a usb drive and i reached to boot options by prssing f12 key. but there is no USB option, options are Hard Drive, CD/DVD and network

Comment: How did you format the drive ?

Comment: In my Dell laptop there is the menu in the bios.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the USB Boot option is not forbidden in BIOS menu. Enter it in the menu with pressing F2.