# No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority

Tags: boot, xubuntu, 32-bit

When I'm trying to boot my PC from the Xubuntu minimal CD, it fails. It just goes straight to the other operating system, windows vista.

I don't have admin access is that occurring the problem? My computer is really old. It is the 32 bit.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to configure your BIOS to boot from CD also there is no minimal Xubuntu. Can you please be more clear and add more details?

Comment: Probably the regular Ubuntu minimal CD is being used here, [since that's visibly and officially recommended on Xubuntu's download page](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) for situations where CD media must be used. @NikolasEarl How did you write mini.iso to a CD? And how did you attempt to boot from it? As xangua says, please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: The "core" product for Xubuntu is still in development so there is no Xubuntu minimal CD quite just yet.  What installation disc was used?  What version of the operating system did you attempt to install?

Answer (score 1):

Enter your BIOS setup utility and change the boot sequence so that the CD is the first entry in the list of boot devices. The Ubuntu minimal CD being very small (<40MB) and text only should be able to boot successfully, even on older systems where the graphical Ubuntu live DVD/USB does not boot successfully. There is no need to use a different Xubuntu CD, because you can select and install the Xubuntu desktop from the *Software selection* menu inside the Ubuntu minimal CD installer.

You should be able to enter the BIOS setup utility without administrative rights, unless it is password protected by an unknown password, and even so you can remove the BIOS password by removing the CMOS battery from the motherboard for 5 minutes and then putting it back in. This will also reset all BIOS/UEFI settings back to their defaults.

[image: CMOS battery]
<sup>**CMOS battery**</sup>