# HP Installation Challenges - Won't Boot and Can't get to BIOS

Tags: boot, hp, bios

I am new to Ubuntu on the desktop - though I've used Linux on servers for years. Finally ditching Windows. I have successfully installed on laptop. Now I'm doing my desktop. I have an HP Eny 700 PC.

I logged into BIOS and switched boot order. I rebooted to USB flash drive. I installed 19.04. I erased and installed to my HDD. All worked - until reboot.

After reboot, Ubuntu did not boot. And I could no longer access BIOS. Basically, my system is DOA.  There probably aren't hardware errors. But I'm trying to clear BIOS by bleeding battery power. Any ideas. BTW, I'm checking  previou answers. Nothing found - thus far.

Comment: Are you able to get to/see the GRUB menu? re: the BIOS... can you still get to the BIOS by hitting the appropriate function key at power up (F2?). Are you able to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: No grub and I can't even get to the BIOS using function keys. I do eventually get a blue HP logo when I wait. I'm assuming this means something. But what it means, I cannot say. If I do hit F10, I get some words. Odd thing is I can't boot from USB drive that I booted from in order to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you pulled the CMOS battery from the motherboard? If so, with the computer disconnected from AC power, push and hold the power button for 15 seconds to really drain the PS charge. Then reinsert the battery and retry.

Comment: I haven't pulled CMOS battery. I did unplug power. I also depressed power (while unplugged) for forty seconds. No joy. If I pull CMOS, I assume that i should depress (and hold) power switch for a while.,

Comment: First, make sure that you properly ground yourself so that you don't static discharge damage your motherboard. Yes, carefully remove the CMOS battery, and then follow my earlier instructions. Wait for a couple of minutes to reinsert the battery.

Comment: The battery was fine. But I replaced it anyway. I could get into BIOS. In fact, the system demanded that I do so. I reset BIOS. Upon reboot, goodness was restored.

Comment: I know that you're new here. Here is how it works. You come with a question/problem. Somebody takes the time and energy to come up with a solution, and documents it in an answer. If the answer solves the problem, you acknowledge them and show appreciation by accepting their answer, by clicking the grey checkmark icon just to the left of the answer. This also lets future readers know that the answer had the best solution for the problem. Make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old zt computer tower isn't booting from xubuntu minimal cd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/old-zt-computer-tower-isnt-booting-from-xubuntu-minimal-cd)

Answer (score 3):

re: "*After reboot, Ubuntu did not boot. And I could no longer access BIOS. Basically, my system is DOA. There probably aren't hardware errors.*"

From the comments...

First, make sure that you properly ground yourself so that you don't static discharge damage your motherboard. With the computer disconnected from AC power, carefully remove the CMOS battery. Then push and hold the power button for 15 seconds to really drain the PS charge. Wait for a couple of minutes to reinsert the battery. Reconnect the AC power and retry accessing the BIOS and booting Ubuntu.

**Update #1:**

After replacing the CMOS battery, and resetting the BIOS, the computer is operational again.