# Upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.1 now can not open bios

Tags: boot, bios

After upgrading to 20.04.1
Can not find away to open the bios.
Thought it might be software so upgraded 21.? then to Ubuntu 21.04.
This did not solve problem.
Went to the mother board MSI I have not got an answer to how to get to the Bios.
Any body have an idea?
Where should I look?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: BIOS settings are accessed before Ubuntu loads. Ubuntu has nothing to do with accessing your BIOS, and upgrading Ubuntu won't help.

Comment: Plesse edit your question and add some more info about what you have tried or what you would habe expected

Comment: Also what kind of computer you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority)