# How do I enable AMD-V when I forget my bios password?

Tags: virtualbox, bios, 22.04, vagrant

Is there any walkaround to enable AMD-V without enabling it manually from the bios setting? My AMD-V left disabled and I forget my BIOS password. Now I want to run Vagrant along with Virtual Box on my computer and it requires AMD-V to be enabled but I have forgotten my BIOS password is there anyway I can enable without going to the BIOS?

NOTE: I am using **Lenovo Thinkpad X140e**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, AFAIK, there is no way to enable AMD-V without BIOS access. At this point, you have three options:

1. Try as hard as you can to remember the password. This is probably your best bet.
2. Buy a new Lenovo Thinkpad X140e motherboard, open up your laptop, and replace the motherboard. That will get rid of the password-protected BIOS entirely. Looks like they sell for $30 a piece on eBay. https://www.ebay.com/itm/223902265114
3. Research some hacky method to reset the password. Looking through Google snippets, it looks like you can short a security chip on the motherboard. You could damage your hardware doing stuff like this, and the websites you'll find this info on may or may not be reliable, and may or may not be safe to visit (i.e., warning, potential malware ahead!). I would really not recommend this route.

Answer (score 0):

There is no workaround to modifying any UEFI setting if UEFI is password protected and you don't know the password.

If you have proof of purchase you may try contacting the manufacturers tech support and ask for solution.

Comment: Sadly, Lenovo themselves state that the only method they allow for fixing a forgotten BIOS password is to replace the motherboard entirely.