# Can't enter BIOS on ACER laptop

Tags: boot, lubuntu, bios, secure-boot

I had installed the latest Lubuntu(22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)) on an old ACER laptop by deleting everything on it (chose the Erase all option) on the partitioning step of the installation, but still, the computer wouldn't boot to Lubuntu. After some googling, I found out I needed to disable secure boot, so I set a supervisor password and disabled secure boot. Now whenever I turn on the laptop, It's stuck on the Acer logo, and I can't even enter BIOS by pressing F2.

Comment: You've provided no details as to what Lubuntu release you're asking about, Lubuntu ISOs are QA-tested & work in BIOS/legacy, uEFI & Secure-uEFI when the ISO is written correctly to installation media and you gave no clues as to how you wrote the ISO (*you can write it so it'll only boot/install on legacy, or uEFI or Secure-uEFI, but if written as intended it'll work in all three!*).  Why disable secure boot?  You've not said what source told you to do that? nor what release & ISO write method it was intended for, nor if that matches how you did. Currently we have too few specifics to help.

Comment: If you follow the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/1/Installing_lubuntu.html); you're installation media will boot & install to all three boot methods (*legacy*, uEFI & Secure-uEFI) so you need make no changes to your system.. I've provided a link to the latest *stable* release as you didn't mention release details; adjust URL if you're using the LTS release for example (*you didn't specify*).

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 22.04 is the 2022-April release (thus 22.04 using the *year.month* format), thus was 3 releases ago.  The *latest* release is Ubuntu 23.04 or the 2023-April release (22.10 the next oldest release).  Be specific & avoid *vague* terms like *latest* unless accurate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority)