# How to enable Intel VT-X in Linux without access to BIOS because it is password protected?

Tags: virtualization, intel, bios

The Laptop is Lenovo 41-70 with Intel CPU and 8 gigs of RAM. The BIOS is password protected, and I could not reset the password by clearing nvram. The disassembly of the laptop and taking out the battery is out of question, so how to enable the VT-X bit in the Intel CPU MSR register from within Linux?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority). Sorry, there's no other way to reset the BIOS password.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and [*official* flavors of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *Your question mentions nothing on-topic for this site, this isn't a Linux Q&A site & hardware/firmware likewise is off-topic here except where specific to something on-topic*