# How To Install Ubuntu On HP Laptops (No AHCI)

Tags: system-installation, hp, raid, bios, ahci

I was just wondering, has anyone else installed Ubuntu on an HP computer recently? They locked their BIOS, so I can't access the advanced tab to reformat my drives from RAID to AHCI or another type readable by Linux. Does anyone have any advice about how to access the advanced tab or alternate methods of switching to AHCI? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: In the case that your bios is on a non-volatile chip, well, you'll be amazed how helpful Youtubers have been if you search for your model computer there.

Comment: The problem is that the advanced bios is locked on hp laptops. Are there any 3rd party tools to change to AHCI? There aren't any YouTube videos that help.