# Reset BIOS password on Ubuntu

Tags: bios

I've been using ubuntu on my HP Elitebook G3 3rd generation for a number of years now.
Recently, I downloaded multipass, and, on launch it, it tells me that KVM support is now enabled on my machine. A search tells me to go into the BIOS and turn in on. But, the BIOS wants a password. I do not know the BIOS password? On Ubuntu, is there a way to find it out/change it?

Thanks in advance,
ValleyDragon

(I’m sorry. This question is not specifically about Ubuntu, but stack overflow won’t let me delete it and re-ask it on a more appropriate stack exchange site.)

Comment: Your BIOS or *firmware* password is a device password, and your installed OS is not involved.  ie. Ubuntu cannot allow you to enter, though some USB *live* media has option to cause BIOS/firmware to start, but you'll still be asked for a password. Your question is device specific & not a Ubuntu question.  FYI:   I don't fully understand your issue; you don't mention Ubuntu product/release, but appear to only want to enter your *firmware* settings (ie. BIOS) which is a machine function, not an OS feature.

Comment: Ubuntu password and BIOS password are completely two different things. If you didn't set the BIOS password yourself, you should ask the people who provided you this computer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I no longer have contact with the people who provided me this computer. Is there a way to reset the BIOS password?

Comment: To reset the BIOS/firmware password, you'll need to deal with the manufacturer of the device for details. Some older systems could be done via simply removing battery (*for a period of time*), or shorting a pin on the motherboard (*again for a period of time*); but most require returning to manufacturer/repairer for chip swap but that's economically un-viable. The intended way is to enter the password; and within firmware settings you select BIOS/firmware option to reset password which will return it to null/deactivated (ie. *password is required first*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No admin access to BIOS to change boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528165/no-admin-access-to-bios-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: If I can’t access this question here which stack exchange site CAN I use?? I don’t see one that would accept this question!

Answer (score 2):

As the others said in the comments, the BIOS password is completely different thing than your OS password.

[HP claims](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06368824):

> A forgotten BIOS password cannot be reset by HP. HP is committed to
> the security and privacy of our customers. To resolve a forgotten BIOS
> password issue, a system board replacement is required, and additional
> customer costs apply.

On the other hand, there are tools that can generate a master password for your BIOS. So you can try using https://bios-pw.org/ or similar tool.

To better understand how such tools work, you can read [BIOS Password Backdoors in Laptops](https://dogber1.blogspot.com/2009/05/table-of-reverse-engineered-bios.html).