# How start ubuntu from a bootable USB stick

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I made a bootable USB stick and I made sure to follow the guide lines. As far as I can tell nothing went wrong when creating the USB stick but somehow I can't find out how to boot ubuntu from the stick. I tried restarting my laptop as guide lines suggest but it only starts Windows again. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the BIOS/UEFI settings, did you put the USB before the hard disk in the boot order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something not set correctly in BIOS. So first go to the BIOS (look which Fxx key is the "BIOS-entry" key on your model of computer) and look around. There may be **Allow USB boot** option somewhere. If there is -> enable it. Than search for Boot order menu. You should set the "boot from USB" before "boot from HD". Make sure that you have the bootable USB pluged in before entering to BIOS. My machine for example, didn't give me "boot from USB" option if there was no bootable USB plugged in. If you see somewhere **Fast boot** option (or similar) -> disable it. You can also set the BIOS to **Legacy mode**.

Hope you get it working!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you press F2 or F8 or F10 when your PC is booting will open the boot menu. Pay attention to the info showed on screen to notice what key will do that.

Comment: Could you expand upon your answer? This seems to be only part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the partition is active.

1. Boot to Windows.
2. Open Disk Management
   In Win7 or Vista: Click Start > in the Search box, type diskmgmt.msc     and then click the diskmgmt.msc higher up.
   In Win XP: Click Start > click Run > type diskmgmt.msc and click OK
3. Select Disk Management.
4. Right-click on the Primary partition you want to mark as Active and
5. select Mark Partition as Active.

Press respective keys during boot and select boot from USB. This option varies from bios to bios.

If the following doesn't work then try using other tools to create live USB.

Personally I prefer Linux Live USB creator. It works very fine.
http://www.linuxliveusb.com

Answer (score 0):

Boot up into windows, find the power menu (restart and shutdown menu) and hold shift and press restart. When a menu comes up select USB device and select your USB.