# Trying to install Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire laptop!

Tags: usb, laptop, acer

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu from my USB stick to my **Acer Aspire** laptop.  I already used **Rufus** to install the *Ubuntu ISO* file on the USB stick. But I can't figure out how to install the Ubuntu from it to my laptop.

I tried pressing **F12** and rebooting, but nothing happened. What do I need to do ?

Comment: Is F12 the boot command to boot to different media?

Comment: I'm don't know!

Comment: You have to set the __boot order__ in the __BIOS__ so it boot __first__ from __usb__. Go to your bios and change the boot order.

Comment: When your computer starts up, look for something titled "boot menu". If you don't see that, your BIOS options might be configured to do a quick boot. You can press Escape, Delete, F7 through F12. When I google "Acer Aspire boot menu", I see a result stating "The "F12 Boot Menu" must be enabled in BIOS. It is disabled by default". When I google "Acer Aspire bios", I see several references to pressing F2 immediately. You'll have to go into the BIOS and enable the F12 boot menu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on an Acer with preinstalled Windows 10 Home](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886536/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-an-acer-with-preinstalled-windows-10-home)

Answer (score 0):

Shut down the computer and insert the USB-stick.

Then hold the **F2** key before hitting the power button and don't release it until you get to the bios settings. You may hear a loud beep, don't be alarmed, that's normal. Once you're inside the bios, you will have to change the boot order. Use the **arrow keys** and the **return key** for navigation. The exact wording may vary, but set it up, so that the pc checks for a bootable usb stick first and then for the drive you want to install Ubuntu on.

Then look for an option like "save and exit". Your pc will then reboot to the Ubuntu USB-stick. The installation process from the stick is self-explanatory.

After the installation, you may want to revisit the bios settings and disable all boot options except the drive you just installed Ubuntu on, to speed up the booting process in the future.

Have fun with your device!

Edit: The **F2** key works on most acer machines. I myself have an Acer Aspire ES15 and I installed it that way. If it does not work, try all the other **function keys**, the **DEL** key, and the **Esc** key. If all of that does not work, your machine must be haunted.