# Can't boot to USB after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, uefi

I have just installed Ubuntu on a Gigabyte mini PC. 
Now I want to boot from the USB (to scrap the install and start again).
The PC won't boot from the USB anymore (even though I put it first in the boot order and disable the HD).

Is this something to do with UEFI?

Comment: Try it on another machine, chances are the issue is with the USB.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

There was another sub-menu - Hard Drive BBS Priorities.

I went in there and selected the USB and disabled the others.