# Bootable drive option not showing while dual booting Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 along with Windows 8.1 but I am unable to do so. I created a bootable flash drive and whenever I restart my system to initiate the installation process, I don't get the bootable drive option in the boot manager.

I had already installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop once but due to some issues I had to remove it. So I deleted the corresponding partition but wasn't able to perform bot repair. Even now when I start my system I get a GRUB windows. Does this have anything to do with the problem I am having? I tried boot repair but I don't know for some reasons it always failed.

So what is the problem here and what can I do to fix it? My system is using UEFI.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot?

Comment: @WillemK will this work?

Comment: Depending on the bios it may help to boot from the flash drive. By the way,  did you set the boot flag on the flash drive?

Comment: @WillemK I don't know how to set the boot flag on the flash drive. Doesn't it automatically gets generated when we make the flash drive bootable? And is it possible that the flash drive itself doesn't support USB booting?

Comment: Depends on the program you create the usb with. Did you check in the bios to allow boot from usb? Also, check the drive with Disk Mgmnt for the bootflag. The flashdrive does support booting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)