# Downloading Ubuntu from a USB

Tags: dual-boot

I have downloaded Ubuntu onto a bootable usb. I want to dual boot my laptop to run Ubuntu, so I turn off my laptop and turn it back on with the usb in the laptop. I am not given the option to dual boot or even run Ubuntu.

It would be great if someone could help me, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority) and [How do I make a bootable Ubuntu USB?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287064/)

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to access your laptop's bios to enable USB booting. The instructions to do this are unique to your laptop, however; you should be able to find instructions from your laptop manufacturer if you punch your model number into google.

Alternatively, you could burn the image to a DVD and run it off of your internal DVD drive if your laptop has one.