# Can't access BIOS on dual boot system 18.04 with Win10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

I boot my system and hammer the `Esc`, `F2`, and `Delete` keys. The system flashes the *Lenovo* logo for a split-second, and then goes straight to GRUB. I continue hammering the `F2` key and the system will boot to Ubuntu or Windows depending on which one I select. Throughout this process there's no chance to get into the BIOS like I could in the good old days despite my hammering of all top row keys on my keyboard (`Esc`, `F2`, etc).

I've tried to access the `UEFI Firmware settings` similar to the screen below. Every option is there `System Restore`, `System Image Recovery`, etc. EXCEPT the one I need `UEFI Firmware settings`. It's simply missing.

How do I get into my BIOS?

[image]

Comment: I have a Lenovo (T440S); at startup it says "To interrupt the boot process press Enter". Did you consider the Enter button as well? (It's not in the top row ;-)

Comment: [How to Enter the BIOS on Your Computer](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/enter-bios-computer/) may help.

Comment: Try full cold boot/power down and then press F-key(s) for your system to get into UEFI. Details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/652966/unable-to-access-bios-menu-after-installing-windows-8/653006#653006

Comment: `Enter` key didn't work. Cold boot didn't help either, but thanks. I used to be able to get in the BIOS, even with dual boot. Can't anymore since the 18.04 upgrade.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: Is it a Lenovo laptop? IIRC some Lenovo laptops have hard keys on side to access bios.

Comment: Use the blue "ThinkVantage" button above the function keys to get into the UEFI settings. Looks like Windows changed what they offer on the screen you posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not access directly in the BIOS with F2 or Del you probably did not do a good boot of Windows at first.When you want to have a dual boot, you first need to install windows with the correct BIOS settings and then boot 18.04.You must avoid UEFI mode in bios,try with legacy mode.
Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I realize it is an old topic, but yesterday I encountered the same issue on a Lenovo T520 with Windows 10 (dual booting with GRUB). No UEFI settings in Windows advanced startup and pressing Enter, Del or F1 on Lenovo screen doing nothing.

I had success in entering UEFI settings, however, by `hitting Enter then F1 in quick succession while on Lenovo boot screen`.