# How can I launch windows 10 usb on ubuntu 3.7

Tags: windows-10

I am using Ubuntu, but I have bought Windows 10 USB stick. There are some .exe files to launch it. I cant open them on ubuntu. How can I launch the Windows 10?

Comment: What do you mean by Ubuntu 3.7?

Comment: Maybe the Windows 10 USB stick has its own bootloader. Try booting with the Window 10 USB stick inserted into a USB port, enter the BIOS/UEFI setup utility, and set the USB stick to boot first in the [boot priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/).

Answer (score 0):

You can run windows program with by using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) or create a virtual machine under [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to run Windows.

Comment: Wine can launch Windows programs, but I've never heard of anyone using Wine to launch Windows itself before. OTOH the .exe files that are on the Windows 10 USB stick must be there for a good reason. It would be nice to know what these .exe files are supposed to do.