# Boot Menu Stuck at GNU GRUB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

I have recently tried to replace my Ubuntu with windows 7. But it won't work.
I first boot my USB drive using woeusb (winusb) but when I restart my device and boot from usb drive GRUB prompt opens. I don't know which command should I use to simply boot from usb drive to install Windows 7. Anyone please tell me the correct and simple commands to do so.
Note: when I enter *ls* in grub menu it shows (hd0,msdos1) , (hd1).
I am having my USB drive as Dev/sda1.

So please send command according to above information. 
Thanks.

Comment: Possible off-topic question.  You use your hardware BIOS/UEFI to select your boot device which is not part of Ubuntu, your current device contains a MBR that I'm assuming is from an old Ubuntu partially deleted. Your fix is machine specific & unrelated to Ubuntu, by telling your BIOS/UEFI to boot your USB device.  Yes you can `chainloader` an OS, but it's not Ubuntu related in my opinion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with the above (by guiverc). You have to tell your PC's BIOS to boot from USB.
On powerup, you'll have to figure out which key to hit to enter the BIOS settings mode. The most common ones I've found are DEL, F2 ,or sometimes F12. Gotta press it at the first splash screen you see, and keep tapping till you get the BIOS. 
If you get the GRUB prompt, power down and try again.
Once you're in BIOS, find the setting to boot from USB. Save and exit, reboot.
Hope this helps!

Comment: It won't work as grub menu opens every time and I am unable to boot from there.