# I can't install Windows 10 alongside my Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

[image: My partitions]

I erased my whole disk and now I only have Ubuntu but I need a windows now so I made a bootable windows 10 usb and I started on legacy boot but computer directly open the Ubuntu. Can you help me please

Update: I installed Ubuntu again in UEFI mode and made my disk GPT but still same thing is happening. See my partitions above.

Comment: You need to change the order of your boot devices in your bios to the win10 usb

Comment: I did that,USB is in the first place but it still opens the ubuntu,it is so weird

Comment: How did you make the bootable windows 10 usb?

Comment: @CCelik *I started on Legacy boot*... WHY? If it's UEFI machine use UEFI mode ONLY for any modern Linux distro and **especially for Windows 10**. And also you should know that you CAN have a dual boot.

Comment: Possivble duplicate of [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue is that you can't boot from the USB itself. If you are spamming the correct key to view the boot options when the computer turns on you should be able to select your flash drive as the boot option.

On most laptops and pcs to view the boot options you have to spam either F9 or ESC as the computer boots up to view the boot options.

Comment: From the comments, it seems op has already set the boot priority properly

Comment: Your advice was for him to change the boot order, I was suggesting that he manually select the USB as the boot option. Small difference but it would give more clarity as to what the issue is rather than praying and hoping it select his USB.

Comment: Either A.) there is something wrong with the MB if it's not obeying the boot options based on priority, or B.) there is something wrong with the usb stick. In either event your suggested solution will not work

Comment: @j-money Agreed. I think the problem here starts because the OP somehow though it woul be a good idea to boot in Legacy mode. So, possibly related to the opposite of what the other answer mentions.

Comment: I tried both UEFI/Legacy and it is not about the USB I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you erase whole disk it is possible that your disk is now converted to mbr.
In order to install uefi version of windows which happens when you boot from a usb, you need change partition table of your entire disk to gpt. Hope it will help.

Comment: It was MBR but I installed Ubuntu again and made the disk GPT but still same thing happens.

Comment: What software you are using to make the bootable usb drive. Maybe you should try to just copy paste the contents of windows 10 iso into the usb, then just restart your computer with legacy bootorder switching off.