# How to make bootable pendrive in Ubuntu with the same Ubuntu version?

Tags: boot

I had booted ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso with my mobile in Live mode (Try Ubuntu). I want to make my pendrive bootable in ubuntu-19.04 without downloading an iso file. 
So where can I find the Ubuntu's bootable file in my Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

1. A copy of the ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso file that you are using needs to be in a place where it can be accessed by Ubuntu that is running in live mode. Copy the ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso file that you already downloaded to your phone so that an Ubuntu live session can browse to it and access it on your phone.
2. Connect a USB flash drive to your phone.
3. Make a bootable USB flash drive using the built-in Startup Disk Creator application. Use the built-in Disks application to find the device name of the USB flash drive, and then check in Startup Disk Creator that you are creating a bootable Ubuntu stick on that flash drive so that you don't accidentally overwrite anything on your phone.
4. In order to boot the Ubuntu live USB that you created on your computer, you must change the boot priority of your computer's BIOS/UEFI so that it boots to the USB flash drive first instead of booting to the OS that is installed on the hard drive. See [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/).