# Cannot press F12 for boot menu

Tags: boot

When I tried to boot ubuntu, I noticed that I should press F12 for the Boot Menu. But my keyboard's F12 and F2 is on the same key.
Normally, I can press Fn+F2 for F12 after the boot process. However, I can't access the boot menu, it only takes me into the BIOS settings(which should be activated using F2). Instead of changing my keyboard, what else can I do? Thanks

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to press any key to boot a correctly installed Ubuntu, single or dual-boot. And the ability to press F12 - one-time boot menu? -, with an actual F12 key or a combo must work independently and regardless of the installed OS or OSes because it's a BIOS/UEFI  feature that can only be used before any OS starts to boot.

Comment: Try without Fn. Sometimes things are reversed pre-boot.

Answer (score 3):

#### Access boot priority menu

The boot priority settings are often found under the Boot tab of the computer's BIOS/UEFI utility. The BIOS/UEFI utility can be accessed by pressing the key which is shown on the manufacturer's splash screen when booting. This is the <kbd>F12</kbd> key on many computers. The keys to press, such as <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, differ on computers from different manufacturers. When grub bootloader is installed it does not change the key which is used to access the BIOS/UEFI utility.

There is a table of keys used to access the BIOS/UEFI setup utility grouped by manufacturer and computer model at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority/1084586#1084586).

#### Access GRUB menu

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you atleast are able to log in to the Ubuntu, then Here is a step by step guide -

So You can't press the Boot menu button because your ubuntu is not detecting the keyboard at all until its completely booted up and login screen is in front of you --

All you have to do is Just login and then edit the grub settings -

1. Open Terminal By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. Enter the Following command and press Enter, if it asks for the password Just enter your password -

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

3. A text editor will open in front of you and now what you have to is change two line in this file

   - If you see something like `GRUB_TIMEOUT=<SOME_NUMBER>` Just put a `#` in front of it.
   - Second is change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden` to `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`
4. Now update the grub by hitting `sudo update-grub`

Now plug in your bootable device, and restart your Ubuntu, and you will presented with a GRUB menu quickly press, up arrow or down arrow button on your keyboard (You have only 3 Seconds) and once you have a menu with the No countdown going on Just press <kbd>Esc</kbd>  on the keyboard and then you will be presented with a Terminal like screen, to exit it type `exit` and hit enter, and you should be now presented with the list of the all your bootable devices, select them and say goodbye to ubuntu forever.