# Bootable USB disk Ubuntu 18.04 gives FreeDOS message

Tags: software-installation

I created bootable USB flash drive using the downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.2 ISO file and Rufus.
I booted up the HP Proliant. Instead of Ubuntu starting, I get a DOS message about FreeDos and the C:> prompt.
The same occurs if I try to run it on my HP Laptop

Comment: Please recreate the flash drive, make sure the second field in Rufus shows _Disk or ISO image_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change boot priority?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208417/how-to-change-boot-priority)

Comment: Thanks title is wrong due to a misunderstanding. It's not the bootable USB disk that gives that message, it's because it's not booting that the already installed FreeDOS gives that message.

Answer (score 2):

Rufus developer here.

Most likely, you are seeing this because you forgot to properly select the ISO in Rufus or changed the *Boot selection* field to `FreeDOS` after you picked the file.

You need to make sure *Boot selection* says something like `ubuntu-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso` (or whatever the name of the ISO you selected is) before you press *START*. If you don't see the name of your ISO when you press *START*, it means that you haven't picked the proper option to create a bootable Ubuntu drive.